# Using a file form field with a Java servlet

Tags: forms, servlets, file-upload

I am tring to retrieve a filename or the file itself for use in a java servlet (from a web form).

I have a file form field:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="SaveDictionary.do">
    <label>
        <input type="file" name="dictionary_file" id="dictionary_file" />
        <br />
    </label>
    <label>
        <br />     
        <input type="submit" name="saveDic" id="saveDic" value="Save Dictionary" />
    </label>
 </form>
```

I wanto then process it in my servlet, what do I do to process this - for a normal text field I would use something like

> String myValue = (String) request.getParameter("parameter_name");

Assuming I have this class, what do I put in the doPost() method to get either the file path or the actual file contents.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SaveDictionary extends HttpServlet {

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
  HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

     // I can't work out what goes here, the same
     // String myValue = (String) request.getParameter("parameter_name"); doesn't work

        response.sendRedirect("dictionary.jsp");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Multipart/form-data](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt) encoded requests are not supported by the default servlet API. You basically need to parse the request body yourself based on the `HttpServletRequest#getInputStream()`. But that's a precious and tedious work. You don't want to do that if you're already asking this question here at SO. Fortunately there's already a robust, thoroughly developed and maintained API out for that, the [Apache Commons FileUpload API](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload). It's in fact easy to use. You can find examples in their [User Guide](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html) and tips&tricks in their [FAQ](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/faq.html).

You can also wrap it in a Filter which does all the parsing work and puts all the parameters back in the request, so that it's all transparent in the servlet code and you can continue using `HttpServletRequest#getParameter()` and consorts the usual way. Uploaded files can then be obtained as request attributes. [Here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/11/multipartfilter.html)'s a basic example.

Hope this helps.